# Delete Blocks of Whitespace in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I often end up with blocks of code like this:

```
public class CustomFile {

    public String path;
    public String name;





    public CustomFile (String pathToFile, String dbName) {
    path = pathToFile;
    name = dbName;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to put my cursor on the line above `public CustomFile` and be able to delete all of the whitespace up to but not including `public String name;`. Is there a command or macro that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like what you want:

```
C-x C-o runs the command delete-blank-lines, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

It is bound to C-x C-o.

(delete-blank-lines)

On blank line, delete all surrounding blank lines, leaving just one.
On isolated blank line, delete that one.
On nonblank line, delete any immediately following blank lines.
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.